# Python - appending json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to append the json files from a folder into variable so i can parse it out later. Here is the code I have:

```
    # Importing dependencies
import os
import shutil
import glob
from zipfile import ZipFile
from datetime import datetime
import zipfile
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import urllib
import sqlalchemy as sa

# Define the folder sources and destinations
MainDir = 'C:/Test/'
LoadingDir =  'C:/Test/Loading/'
ArchiveDir = 'C:/Test/Archive/'

glob_data = []
# Look for all json files in directory
for file in glob.glob(LoadingDir + '*.json'):
    with open(file) as json_file:
        # Load each json file and append it
        data = json.load(json_file)
        i = 0
        while i < len(data):
            glob_data.append(data[i])
            i += 1
with open(LoadingDir + 'Combined.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(glob_data, f, indent=4)
# Load Json file for parsing
file = open(LoadingDir + 'Combined.json')
data = json.load(file)
# Parsing of data
df = json_normalize(data,meta=['timestamp'])
df.to_csv(LoadingDir + "Combined.csv",sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
try:
    df.to_csv(LoadingDir + "Combined.csv",sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
except:
    pass
```

When I try running it I get this message below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-1-ea0f48aa463e> in <module>
     24         i = 0
     25         while i < len(data):
---> 26             glob_data.append(data[i])
     27             i += 1
     28 with open(LoadingDir + 'Combined.json', 'w') as f:

KeyError: 0
```

Here is the sample of my Json file:

```
  {
  "sensor-time" : {
    "timezone" : "America/Los_Angeles",
    "time" : "2019-11-05T14:18:36-08:00"
  },
  "status" : {
    "code" : "OK"
  },
  "content" : {
    "element" : [ {
      "element-id" : 0,
      "element-name" : "Line 0",
      "sensor-type" : "SINGLE_SENSOR",
      "data-type" : "LINE",
      "from" : "2019-11-01T00:00:00-07:00",
      "to" : "2019-11-05T15:00:00-08:00",
      "resolution" : "ONE_HOUR",
      "measurement" : [ {
        "from" : "2019-11-01T00:00:00-07:00",
        "to" : "2019-11-01T01:00:00-07:00",
        "value" : [ {
          "value" : 0,
          "label" : "fw"
        }, {
          "value" : 0,
          "label" : "bw"
        } ]
      }, {
        "from" : "2019-11-01T01:00:00-07:00",
        "to" : "2019-11-01T02:00:00-07:00",
        "value" : [ {
          "value" : 0,
          "label" : "fw"
        }, {
          "value" : 0,
          "label" : "bw"
        } ]
      }, {
        "from" : "2019-11-01T02:00:00-07:00",
        "to" : "2019-11-01T03:00:00-07:00",
        "value" : [ {
          "value" : 0,
          "label" : "fw"
        }, {
          "value" : 0,
          "label" : "bw"
        } ]
      },
```

So what I noticed is that this json file does not start with [ which means its not list of dictionaries. But when i have json that does start with [ my code does work. 
How do I adjust this to work for this sample of json?

Comment: So, you have some json files, that have `[` in it, and some don't?

Comment: The one I am working with on this project do not have [. I was just using other format as an example to say that if it does [ then code works.

Comment: Added an answer, hope it helps; if not let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
import os
import shutil
import glob
from zipfile import ZipFile
from datetime import datetime
import zipfile
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import urllib
import sqlalchemy as sa

# Define the folder sources and destinations
MainDir = 'C:/Test/'
LoadingDir =  'C:/Test/Loading/'
ArchiveDir = 'C:/Test/Archive/'

glob_data = []
# Look for all json files in directory
for file in glob.glob(LoadingDir + '*.json'):
    with open(file) as json_file:
        # Load each json file and append it
        data = json.load(json_file)
        glob_data.append(data)
with open(LoadingDir + 'Combined.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(glob_data, f, indent=4)
# Load Json file for parsing
file = open(LoadingDir + 'Combined.json')
data = json.load(file)
# Parsing of data
df = json_normalize(data,meta=['timestamp'])
df.to_csv(LoadingDir + "Combined.csv",sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
try:
    df.to_csv(LoadingDir + "Combined.csv",sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
except:
    pass
```

You don't need to iterate over the return value returned by json.load(), it's already parsed and converted to a dict, just append it directly.